# I dont know why I get a 400 bad request error for sending a discord webhook. Everything seems fine but I am new at this

Tags: python, discord, webhooks, discord.py

I am new at this so it is probably a stupid mistake

Im trying to make a program that sends the price of a stock quote to discord as a webhook.

The webhook does not send. But, when I do print(symbol.json()["Global Quote"]) I get all of the information.

I think there is a problem with the "Content-Type": "application/json" but im not really sure how to fix it.

This is a snippet:

```py
webhook = 'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/609119785015312414/HOkHGPWqfPfLJHpSp15XZ9dUNhUDly_DKQ8OwLgk3Rw0-4G08gx0mOrKN3FKhompb5ig'
session = requests.session()
symbol = session.get("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=AAPL&apikey=F4RV85MVA2M2YTIY")

data = {}
data["content"] = symbol.json()["Global Quote"]
data["username"] = "AAPL"

result = requests.post(webhook, data=json.dumps(data), headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})

try:
  result.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
  print(err)
else:
  print("Payload delivered successfully, code {}.".format(result.status_code))
```

The output for this is: 400 Client Error: BAD REQUEST for url: https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/609119785015312414/HOkHGPWqfPfLJHpSp15XZ9dUNhUDly_DKQ8OwLgk3Rw0-4G08gx0mOrKN3FKhompb5ig

btw - I deleted the webhook before posting this

Comment: Remove the `try` block to inspect if you get any errors in the console. Also, make sure data["content"] is a string.

Comment: You might have more success using the [`dhooks`](https://github.com/kyb3r/dhooks) packages, which is specifically an API wrapper for Discord Webhooks.  It also allows you to send embeds using the [tag:discord.py] `Embed` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one problem with your code. The webhooks are functioning properly.

`data["content"] = symbol.json()["Global Quote"]`

> In the line data["content"] is a dict while it needs to be a string
>
> You have to convert It to a String

There are two ways to fix this:-

First Way Using  json -

`import json`

Then edit this line `data["content"] = symbol.json()["Global Quote"]` to -

`data["content"] = json.dumps(symbol.json()["Global Quote"])`

Second way-

Edit this line `data["content"] = symbol.json()["Global Quote"]` to -

`data["content"] = str(symbol.json()["Global Quote"])`

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```py
from dhooks import Webhook

hook = Webhook("your-webhook")

hook.send("message-here")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).